# What does NameError mean in python?

Tags: python, nameerror

I cannot get where my error is in my code.

```
def cauculator (num_1,num_2):
    #num_1 is the first number to be cauculated, when num_2 is the second.
    return (a+add+b+sub+c+mul+d+div)

div = num_1/num_2
mul = num_1*num_2
add = num_1+num_2
sub = num_1-num_2

#the reason I did this is because I will use these "subsitute" names to print the result out.\

a= "Added"
b= "Subtracted"
c= "Multiplied"
d= "Divided"

print (a+add+str('\n')+b+sub+str('\n')+c+mul+str('\n')+d+div)

print (cauculator) (3,8)
print (cauculator) (5,2)
print (cauculator) (9,5)
```

When I try to run this, the `NameError` happens.
I do not know where my error is.

Comment: your print function syntax looks weird

Comment: that's not how you call function with parameter!!

Comment: `num1` and `num2` are only defined inside `cauculator()` (they are *local variables*), but you're trying to use them outside of that function.

Comment: The NameError error message normally indicates which name it can't find/resolve. Please, _always_, provide the full error message. Also, is your code properly indented? Are the lines starting from `div = ...` really outside of the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

variables `num1` and `num2` are defined within the scope of function `cauculator` but you are accessing them from the global scope where they are not defined. Your code also has some other issues too. here is an edited version of your code:

```
def cauculator (num_1,num_2):
    #num_1 is the first number to be cauculated, when num_2 is the second.
    div = num_1 / num_2
    mul = num_1 * num_2
    add = num_1 + num_2
    sub = num_1 - num_2
    output_string = f'Added = {add}, Subtracted = {sub}, Multiplied = {mul}, Divided = {div}'
    return output_string


print(cauculator(3, 8))
print(cauculator(5, 2))
print(cauculator(9, 5))
```

feel free to ask if need help understanding it.

Answer (score -1):

Your code contains several bugs. Here is the code that I think you are trying to implement:

```
    #num_1 is the first number to be cauculated, when num_2 is the second.
    return_str = "%d %d\t%d\t\t%d %d\t\t%d\t%d %d\t\t%d\t%d %d\t\t%d" % \
                    (num_1, num_2, num_1+num_2, num_1, num_2, num_1-num_2, 
                    num_1, num_2, num_1*num_2, num_1, num_2, num_1//num_2)
    return return_str

div = "num_1/num_2"
mul = "num_1*num_2"
add = "num_1+num_2"
sub = "num_1-num_2"

# the reason I did this is because I will use these "subsitute" names 
# to print the result out.\

a = "Added"
b = "Subtracted"
c = "Multiplied"
d = "Divided"

# sep is the keyword for seperator to add between comma seperated vales
print (a, add, b, sub, c, mul, d, div, sep = "\t") 

print (cauculator(3, 8))
print (cauculator(5, 2))
print (cauculator(9, 5))
```